# Automate dotnet watch on project load?

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I'm using an extension to recompile scss on save.

The readme says to run this in cmd:
`dotnet watch tool run webcompiler`

It works fine, but that means every project I work on, I have to remember to open a cmd window and leave it there running the dotnet watch.

Is there a way to automate this when I open a project/solution?

Comment: Maybe this extension would work: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=emeraldwalk.RunOnSave